# Writing a Macro for this: (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, macros

I have a method like this:

```
- (CGPoint) _convertCGPointCT2UIKit:(CGPoint)ctPoint{
 CGPoint uikitPoint = CGPointMake(ctPoint.x + INITIAL_HORIZ_OFFSET, 
          self.bounds.size.height - ctPoint.y - INITIAL_VERT_OFFSET);
 return uikitPoint;
}
```

Is there any way I can make this a macro?
I tried this but I get errors like "; expected before )" and so on.

```
#define CGPointUIKit2CT(p) CGPointMake(p.x - INITIAL_HORIZ_OFFSET, self.bounds.size.height - p.y - INITIAL_VERT_OFFSET);
```

thanks in advance.

Ignacio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of rules of thumb to guide you:

- Wrap *everything* in parentheses
- Don't end a macro with a semicolon, that's probably what's generating your errors.  Instead put the semicolon in your code when you use it.

Here's my answer:

```
 #define CGPointUIKit2CT(p) CGPointMake(((p).x) - INITIAL_HORIZ_OFFSET, self.bounds.size.height - ((p).y) - INITIAL_VERT_OFFSET)
```

Answer (score 2):

While there may be reasons to avoid method dispatch for something like this, there is no reason to do it as a macro instead of a static inline function:

```
static inline
CGPoint CGPointUIKit2CT(UIView *self, CGPoint  ctPoint) {
  CGPoint uikitPoint = CGPointMake(ctPoint.x + INITIAL_HORIZ_OFFSET,
      self.bounds.size.height - ctPoint.y - INITIAL_VERT_OFFSET);'

  return uikitPoint;
}
```

That will compile out to the same thing as a macro, but will provide better debugging and profiling information.